# external JavaScript File not working in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular2-template

I am building a web app with Angular 2 framework and I want to use an external template. Trying to convert it into an angular2 SPA.

I need to run some scripts (custom.js). All CSS and JavaScript file are added in Index.html.

Everything is working fine except external js. JavaScripts are not working properly. But the CSS files are working. Material components and modals other JavaScript functionality nothing is working inside angular component file.

Comment: add the `external js` file above the angular js in your html

Comment: angular1.0 material design won't work for angular2. There is new material components released by google best compatible with angular4. here is the url :- https://material.angular.io

Answer (score 0):

In your .angular-cli.json file you need to add the external js file under your app's scripts property.

```
    {
        // other app config
        apps:[
            {
                // Your app config
                "scripts":[
                    "path/to/your/custom.js"
                ]
            }
         ]
    }
```

If you would like to use the script in a component, you should declare it before the component class.

```
declare var customLibraryName: any;
```

See the [Angular Cli Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks @JosephDragovich for your fast reply. To be honest, I am a fresher in Javascript and angular 2. Following your suggestion, I updated my code as below:  "scripts": [
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-plugin-collection.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/custom.js"
      ], work nothing

Answer (score 0):

thanks @JosephDragovich for your fast reply. To be honest, I am a fresher in Javascript and angular 2. Following your suggestion, I updated my code as below:
javaScript not working

angular-cli.json

```
  "scripts": [
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-ui.min.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/jquery-plugin-collection.js",
        "./src/assets/Js/custom.js"
      ],
```

my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LocumMedApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="has-side-panel side-panel-right fullwidth-page side-push-panel">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

place script in index.html also using `<script>` tag.